# Is it possible to set a fixed on-screen position for the User Location Pin on MKMapView?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit, mapkit

I'm trying to set up a **MKMapView** in a way that the user's location would always be offset in the top right corner of the view controller, and I would build the rest of my UI around that "block".

Is there a way to set a fixed/offset center point for the **MKMapView** for example in a way that the pin is always at an x, y position on the screen?

I can provide a sketched example if you are having trouble understanding my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out just now,

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation!) {
    // Define a span (for zoom)
    let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005)

    // Get user location
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
      latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude,
      longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude
    )

    // Get the close region for the user's location
    // This zooms into the user's tracked location
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
    let adjusted = mapView.regionThatFits(region)
    mapView.setRegion(adjusted, animated: true)

    // Here we set the offset of the map to be 75% to the right
    // and 15% from the top. Gives us a nice top right view.
    var rect = mapView.visibleMapRect
    let point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(location)
    rect.origin.x = point.x - rect.size.width * 0.75
    rect.origin.y = point.y - rect.size.height * 0.15
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(rect, animated: true)
}
```

Pablo A.'s answer was a good starting point, but sadly it wasn't enough to do what I was looking for.

I went ahead and added a mask view on top of the map view as well to better visualize what kind of UI I was going for in the end.

[image: MKMapView Example]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the pixel coordinates to map coordinates in order to know where to add your pin, and update it every time the map region is changed:

```
CGPoint fakecenter = CGPointMake(20, 20);
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [mapView convertPoint:fakecenter toCoordinateFromView:mapView];
```

Comment: So this would basically mean that I would have hide the user location but keep following the user and use my own pin?

Comment: Actually, after reading twice what you try to do, you should be able to get the diff between the user user coordinate and the previous computed coordinate and center the map in `user location - diff`.

Comment: Previously computed coordinate you mean the fakecenter position?

Comment: Exactly, the coordinate from the fakecenter.

Comment: The pixel coordinates are relative to the map, right? I need to get it relative to the screen.